# Update Date with Javascript into Textbox add Months and correct year etc

Tags: javascript, php

So the premise is there is a text box that denotes the start date then another input box which `onchange` should run a  javascript function that adds the value of months in the tenure box to the contract start date and give a contract end date.

I have tried the following code:

```
<form name="FormName">
Contract Start Date: <input type="text" name="Start" value="<?php echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>" onchange="myFunction()" />
<br />
Tenure (Months): <input type="text" name="Months" value="" onchange="myFunction()" />
<br />
Contract End Date: <input type="text" name="TextBoxName" value="" />

</form>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var val = document.forms["FormName"].elements["Months"].value;
var d = new Date(document.forms["FormName"].elements["Start"].value);
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth() + val;
var day = d.getDate();
document.forms["FormName"].elements["TextBoxName"].value = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
}
</script>
```

But this does not seem to deal with it as a date object and I get values back like 2014/22/31 where 22 is the months and should obviously carry over to the year component.

I'm guessing its treating it as a string when the var's are defined into they're seperate Year, Month, Day parts... I need it to return a date that is in the format as `date("Y/m/d");` in PHP.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try constructing a new Date from the updated values

Comment: why are You adding  + val in your month? I think this is the problem.

Comment: [*getMonth()*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.12) returns a number (0-11) to which you are just adding another number, so a December date (month number 11) plus 10 months gives 21. It does not adjust the Date object, use [*setMonth()*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.38) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around and searching the net I implemented the [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) library. This resolved a lot of the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

as @user2310289 suggested, you should do this:

```
var endDate = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+val));
var year = endDate.getFullYear();
var month = endDate.getMonth();
var day = endDate.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is to correctly parse the date string. The format you are using is not one specified in ES5 so it will be entirely implementation dependent unless you parse it yourself. So:

```
// Parse y/m/d to create a Date
function parseString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2]);
}
```

Once you convert the string to a Date, you can add months:

```
var d = parseString(document.forms["FormName"].elements["Start"].value);

// Copy d for use later
oDate = d.getDate();
d.setMonth(d.getMonths() + Number(val));
```

You will have cases where you add months to a date that is say 31 July that will evaluate to say 31 June which will automatically be converted to 1 July.

You can fix this by looking at the date. If the adjusted date is not the same as the start date, set the adjusted date to the last day of the previous month by setting the date to 0, e.g.

```
if (d.getDate() != oDate) {
  d.setDate(0);
}
```

Note that subtracting months may not get you back to the start, e.g.

```
Jan 31 + 1 month => 28 Feb // for a non-leap year
28 Feb - 1 month => 28 Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// let your contract start date be '2013/12/11'
var c_start_date = '2013/12/10';
var tenure = 5; // 5 months

var c_start_date_obj = new Date(c_start_date);

var c_end_date_obj = new Date(c_start_date_obj.getFullYear(), c_start_date_obj.getMonth() + tenure, c_start_date_obj.getDate());

var c_end_date = c_end_date_obj.getFullYear() + '/' + c_end_date_obj.getMonth() + '/' + c_end_date_obj.getDate();

alert(c_end_date);
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2trd7/)

Comment: So 31-Jan-2014 + 1 month => 3-March-2014? You are also not accounting for the month index being 0 to 11, not 1 to 12 (*cf* `c_end_date_obj.getMonth()`).

Comment: @RobG:as per question, the date format must be in `y/m/d`. So when i convert it into date format, then there is no need to maintain a month  from  0 to 11. Date object `new Date()` automatically do that.

Comment: Nothing to do with `new Date()` (which is flawed per my comment on the OP) but with formatting the returned string (per my comment on your answer).